# Android Studio new activity layout black screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-layout

I'm coding/trying to code for my school project. I'm having trouble with creating a second activity.

With exercise files from the Android Developer website everything works.
But in my main Project file every time I open the XML file of the new created empty activity (here: `DayView`) it's a black screen. I ignored it and tried to run the app but it didn't work when the second activity is called.

I'd be very happy if someone could help me. Since I'm very new at this let me know what I need to do better next time when writing in this threads.

[image]

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.classagenda.ca.classagenda">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DayView"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>`
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.classagenda.ca.classagenda;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         //   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
           // setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }

        /** Called when the user taps the Send button */
        public void Montag(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DayView.class);
           // EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
           // String message = editText.getText().toString();
           // intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }`
```

DayView Second Activity:

```
 package com.classagenda.ca.classagenda;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class DayView extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_day_view);

        }
    }
```

layout activity_day_view.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.classagenda.ca.classagenda.DayView"
>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DayView"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="214dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="106dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: In activity_day_view.xml, add textColor to TextView. Set it to white and check.

Comment: I don't get whats the issue? Your theme is just a dark one. You can add buttons and change the background to white. Don't sweat it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Problem solved! It was late at night so I overreacted. My bad:/